# how to download MP3 files from Spotify platform?

Tags: spotify

I would like to know how to download MP3 files from Spotify platform? Because I am a free Spotify user, I cannot download some of my favorite songs. Is there any way to download MP3 files from the Spotify platform?

Comment: Someone suggested me to use TuneSolo Spotify Music Converter, has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 2):

There might be, but any method you would be using would be illegal, as this is not within the user agreement imposed on you if you use the free version. So do not attempt this.